# Docusign: sign and upload pdf documents. User sets position for signing field

Tags: docusignapi

We are thinking about using the Docusign API to make signing documents possible in our own app. I am currently unsure if I can implement our ideas using the docusign api.

We have a platform where you can upload and manage documents (PDF). The idea is that a user can click on an uploaded document, sign it and then upload it again. Each document looks different, so we just want to give the user the option to set a signature field and sign it himself.

Here is a short example of our idea:

- User selects PDF document (in our app) and clicks on a button called "sign".
- A new frame opens (with Docusign UI, if possible?).
- The user sets the position of the signature field, signs it himself and presses "save".
- The signed document is uploaded to our app as a PDF document.

Can this be done using the Docusign API?

Our App is built with nodejs.

Many thanks in advance :)

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is a specific part of the scenario you need help with. Yes, the scenario above is possible to implement with our DocuSign APIs.

You'd need to create an envelope with the uploaded PDF documents and send it over to the user. They can then sign/add tabs where they like to sign.

Let us know if you need specific clarification.